# How to join entries in a set into one string?

Tags: python, list, set, python-2.7

Basically, I am trying to join together the entries in a set in order to output one string. I am trying to use syntax similar to the join function for lists. Here is my attempt:

```
list = ["gathi-109","itcg-0932","mx1-35316"]
set_1 = set(list)
set_2 = set(["mx1-35316"])
set_3 = set_1 - set_2
print set_3.join(", ")
```

However I get this error: `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'join'`

What is the equivalent call for sets?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
', '.join(set_3)
```

The `join` is a string method, not a set method.

Comment: if your set contains integers/longs you must use `', '.join(str(s) for s in set_3)`

Answer (score 36):

Sets don't have a `join` method but you can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead.

```
', '.join(set_3)
```

The `str.join` method will work on any iterable object including lists and sets.

Note: be careful about using this on sets containing integers; you will need to convert the integers to strings before the call to join.  For example

```
set_4 = {1, 2}
', '.join(str(s) for s in set_4)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `join` is called on the string:

```
print ", ".join(set_3)
```

Answer (score 5):

Set's do not have an order - so you *may* lose your order when you convert your list into a set, i.e.:

```
>>> orderedVars = ['0', '1', '2', '3']
>>> setVars = set(orderedVars)
>>> print setVars
('4', '2', '3', '1')
```

Generally the order will remain, but for large sets it almost certainly won't.

Finally, just incase people are wondering, you don't need a ', ' in the join.

Just:  ''.join(set)

:)

Answer (score 4):

Nor the `set` nor the `list` has such method `join`, string has it:

```
','.join(set(['a','b','c']))
```

By the way you should not use name `list` for your variables. Give it a `list_`, `my_list` or some other name because `list` is very often used python function.

Answer (score 4):

You have the join statement backwards try:

```
print ', '.join(set_3)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just have it backwards.

```
print ", ".join(set_3)
```

Comment: Invalid syntax no? `print(", ".join(set_3))`

Comment: It's valid in 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method that handles the following edge-cases:

- Set size one. A `", ".join({'abc'})` will return `"a, b, c"`. My desired output was `"abc"`.
- Set including integers.
- Empty set should returns `""`

```
def set_to_str(set_to_convert, separator=", "):
        set_size = len(set_to_convert)
        if not set_size:
            return ""
        elif set_size == 1:
            (element,) = set_to_convert
            return str(element)
        else:
            return separator.join(map(str, set_to_convert))
```

Comment: Could have used `" ".join({'abc'})` to get the desired o/p `"abc"`. [executable code in repl.it](https://repl.it/@abhijeetbhanjadeo/settostr)

Comment: Interesting. Just realized that set('abc') and {'abc'} have different behaviors. That's what threw me off.

Comment: I have updated the [executable code](https://repl.it/@abhijeetbhanjadeo/settostr) to operate for [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) & [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: FYI, {'abc'} is a set. And `"".join(set(ip_data))` gives a randomized order of the letters (example, 'bca') because set creates three elements {'a', 'b', 'c'} but does not preserves order.