# Removes braces from variable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am comparing two list:

```
gp_yu = set(agencys_sp2).intersection(gp_list_t)
```

the output is in braces like this `{900}`. What can i do to remove the braces

Comment: You are getting a set object

Comment: This is more a semantical discussion: the braces mean that this is a set: the intersection can contain zero, one, or more elements. So what do you actually want? An element? then which one? What if the set is empty? or contains two elements or more?

Comment: just the element without the  {}

Comment: @LukeLuvevou: what if there are two elements, or no element?

Comment: i will handle that on my code..

Comment: @LukeLuvevou: well you can obtain *an* element of a collection with `next(iter(gp_yu))`, but it looks like a bad idea to handle this with code. Typically one aims to respect code contracts *by design*. Like *Linus Torvalds* said "Bad programmers worry about code, good programmers about data structures and their relations*".

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem i am just a month into python programming so i am just learning as well . I usually code in c# for the last 5 years . This is my first time in python

Comment: @LukeLuvevou: but that does not matter, the core idea of every language is that logic should be described by data structures, and the relations in between. Compare it to a `HashSet<T>` in C#. It is unsafe to simply obtain an element out of the `HashSet<T>`, since it is possible that it contains no elements, one, or multiple. If it contains multiple, it is even not specified in what order you will obtain elements.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem before i apply that code you provide i already have the code to handle if the set is none or does not return any value :  
    if len(gp_list_t) == 1:
                                gp_lits3 = gp_list_t[0]
                            else:
                                stz = next(iter(gp_yu))
                                gp_lits3 = stz
                            agencys_sp = GPSpecial.objects.filter(agencys=user_agency,is_active=True,id = gp_lits3).values_list('agencys')

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for that part with the set returning more than 1 value . I will try and set some rules around it on how the user does the setup for that particular functionality on the front end dashboard.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can i mark your comment as answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain *an* `element` from an *iterable* `iterable` (a `set` is an iterable, but lists, dictionaries, etc. are iterables as well) with:

```
element = next(iter(iterable))
```

In case the iterable contains two or more elements, it will return the *first* element (a set has no really a "first" element in the sense that the order can very over time, but it will return *an* element).

In case the iterable contains *no* elements at all (an empty `set`, `list`, `tuple`, `dict`ionary, etc.), then it will raise a `StopIteration` error. You can however let the expression return a `default` value with:

```
element = next(iter(iterable), default)
```

So in case `iterable` contains one or more elements, the "first" element is returned, in case it is empty, it will return `default`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean some like how to get your set as a string, so just use `join` function.
Some like this `', '.join(gp_yu)`.
Check this topic for more information:
[Python: how to join entries in a set into one string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323782/python-how-to-join-entries-in-a-set-into-one-string)